# How do I insert a simple marker in a Google Maps script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I have a Google Maps script which looks like this (it is place between the `<head></head>` tags):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.500891, 5.439642),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And the following is between `<body></body>` tags:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

So I want to add a red marker like here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Comment: Did you try the code from the example you link to?  What problems are you having with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the code from the example you linked to:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

Adding it to your map (and changing the position to be visible) works for me:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.500891, 5.439642),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: mapOptions.center,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```